# Zipping Folder with Java but Excluding Certain Sub-directories

Tags: java, zip, directory

I managed to find two example snippets of code for zipping a directory with Java:

```
public static void pack(final Path folder, final Path zipFilePath) throws IOException {
    try (
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFilePath.toFile());
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)
    ) {
        Files.walkFileTree(folder, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(folder.relativize(file).toString()));
                Files.copy(file, zos);
                zos.closeEntry();
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(folder.relativize(dir).toString() + "/"));
                zos.closeEntry();
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and

```
public static void pack(String sourceDirPath, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
    Path p = Files.createFile(Paths.get(zipFilePath));
    try (ZipOutputStream zs = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(p))) {
        Path pp = Paths.get(sourceDirPath);
        Files.walk(pp)
          .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path))
          .forEach(path -> {
              ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(pp.relativize(path).toString());
              try {
                  zs.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                  zs.write(Files.readAllBytes(path));
                  zs.closeEntry();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
          });
    }
}
```

But, for both examples, I can't for the life of me figure out how to exclude certain sub-directories within the source directories from being included in the output zip.

Could somebody lend me a hand?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to define your directory filter in the `preVisitDirectory(...)` method such that it returns `FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE` whenever it pre-visits a directory that you would like to exclude.

For more details, see the **Controlling the Flow** section of [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html).

**Edit:**

As requested, a sample implementation using the above provided code. Create an instance of it with paths to the source directory (`srcPath`) and Zip file name (`zipPath`). Add any directory names to be excluded. For example, `addDirExclude( "bin" )` would exclude any directory named `bin`, its files, and any sub-directories thereunder.

This is an example, intended to demonstration one of several ways to further control a file tree walk. ***This is not production quality code; use at your own risk.***

```
public class ZipWithExcludedDirs {
    final private Path         srcPath;
    final private Path         zipPath;
    final private List<String> excludeList = new ArrayList<>();


    public ZipWithExcludedDirs( Path srcPath, Path zipPath ) {
        this.srcPath = srcPath;
        this.zipPath = zipPath;
    }


    public void addDirExclude( String exDir ) {
        excludeList.add( exDir );
    }


    public void pack() throws IOException {
        try ( FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( zipPath.toFile() );
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream( fos ) ) {
            Files.walkFileTree( srcPath, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                public FileVisitResult visitFile( Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs )
                        throws IOException {
                    zos.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( file.toString() ) );
                    Files.copy( file, zos );
                    zos.closeEntry();
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }


                public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory( Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs )
                        throws IOException {
                    String dirName = dir.getFileName().toString();
                    for ( String excl : excludeList )
                        if ( dirName.equals( excl ) )
                            return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;

                    zos.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( dir.toString() + "/" ) );
                    zos.closeEntry();
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            } );
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit (Part Deux)**

I have edited the above code such that it returns `SKIP_SUBTREE` instead of `SKIP_SIBLINGS`, which is what I had originally, but changed for some reason. A glance at the JavaDocs appears to indicate that `SKIP_SUBTREE` and `SKIP_SIBLINGS` have the same effect on the directory being visited. It does. However `SKIP_SIBLINGS` also affects *siblings* of the directory (i.e. files and directories that follow it in the same parent directory).

Furthermore, the original file walker code referenced by OP, causes an erroneous artifact to be included. This was due to the "relativizing" of the `ZipEntry` path. Paths should not adjusted in `SimpleFileVistor`. If there is a need for an archive to be relative or
absolute, then the original `srcPath` should set as such.

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample code? It would mean the world to me!

Comment: I will see what I can do.

Comment: I tested the above code, but instead of excluding just the specified sub-directories in the folder, it excludes everything.

Comment: I tested it myself too - before posting - and it seemed to work, though I wouldn’t vouch for the quality of the code you found. Did you try a test case without specifying any exclusions to make sure your paths are correct? Sprinkle a few `println` around in the visiting methods to see what paths they are touching on. Then again, the purpose of this was to give an example of how to exclude directories in a file tree walk, not to write a zip utility. As I said, its demo code. I got you to the door. You have to walk through it :)

Comment: I think I found the issue - had to change FileVisitResult.SKIP_SIBLINGS to FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE as per your original suggestion. Thank you so very much!

Comment: One last thing, I see the following "file" inside the output zip files:
http://i.imgur.com/ehn2lOE.png
Any ideas what that is?

Comment: It appears that I have a bit of egg on my face :) You are correct, `SKIP_SUBTREE` is the correct return value.  As far as the additional artifact in the resulting ZIP, that is due to the original code. I’ll address both these issues in my answer’s edit shortly.